# laravel edit not working properly after uploading on server

Tags: html, laravel-5, controller

I am trying to edit a post of a user and restricts users to only edit posts that they created. (i referred to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAP8IS_ak6w&t=12s by Traversy Media)

here is what I got so far:

**HTML**

```
      @if (count($posts) > 0)
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            @foreach($posts as $post)
              <tr>
                <td width="80%">{{ $post->title }}</td>
                <td class="display-inline-flex">
                  <a href="{{ url('/posts') }}/{{$post->id}}/edit">Edit</a>
                  {!!Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@destroy', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'style' => 'margin: 0px 20px;'])!!}
                    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
                    {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn-link btn-delete'])}}
                  {!!Form::close()!!}
                </td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      @else
        <p>You have no post yet!</p>
      @endif
```

** ROUTE **

```
// Posts
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Auth::routes();
```

** CONTROLLER **

```
public function edit($id)
 {
     $post = Post::find($id);
     //check for correct user
     if (auth()->user()->id !== $post->user_id) {
       return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'Unauthorized page');
     }
     return view('posts.edit')->with('post', $post);
 }
```

When i test the Edit function on my localhost it works well. but when I uploaded the project and tested it on my server it always redirects to the `Unauthorized page`.

please help me get in track on my development.

thanks in advance!

Comment: A few years back I had the same problem. I worked locally but not on production. It turned out I had to change the `.env` a little bit. The `APP_URL` and/or [`SESSION_DOMAIN`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php#L145) wasn't correct. Might be the same case for you?

Comment: Hi @DeesOomens just tried your suggestion. my `APP_URL` is http://localhost should I change this setting?

Comment: I think the `SESSION_DOMAIN` needs to change. Let's say that your url is `https://stackoverflow.com/`, then your `APP_URL` needs to be: `https://stackoverflow.com` and your `SESSION_DOMAIN` needs to be `stackoverflow.com`. I hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use `Policy` of `laravel`. For reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

Example:  https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/gates-and-policies-in-laravel--cms-29780